# CSS - Media queries - elements not stacking / floating properly

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm setting media queries for tablet-size screens and my nav bar, header logo and top section don't seem to want to stack properly. If I fix the position of the nav I'm losing the section heading or if I put the nav position as static the nav bar is trying to hide behind it. So, when I reduce to 680px or below I get this at the top of my screen -

[image: position static - nav]

Or this -

[image: position fixed - nav]

It all stacks fine at 480px and below so not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here are my media queries -

```css
  @media screen and (max-width: 680px) {
    
        nav {
    
            float: none;
            text-align: center;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            
        }
    
        nav a {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 0;
       
        
        } 
    
        #logo {
    
        height: auto;
        
      }
    
      #logo img {
    
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 21%;
      }
    
    
        section {
            float: none;
            height: auto;
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    
        body {
        max-width: 500px;
    }
    
    
      header {
       
        height: auto;
       
      }
    
      nav {
       
        text-align: center;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
        padding-top: 10px;
        position: static;
    
      }
    
      nav a {
        display: block;
        border-bottom: 0;
       
        
      } 
    
      nav a:hover {
         background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
         color: #fff;
      }
    
      #logo {
    
        height: auto;
        
      }
    
      #logo img {
    
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
        left: 21%;
      }
    
    
      section {
        float: none;
        height: auto;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
```

```html
    <header>
         <div id="logo"> <img src="images/havoc_logo.png"> </div>
      <nav>
        <a href="#logo">Home</a>
        <a href="#whatwedo">What we do</a>
        <a href="#whoweare">Who we are</a>
        <a href="#partners">Who we work with</a>
        <a href="#contact">Say hello</a>
        <a href="Blog">Blog</a>
      </nav>
    
    </header>
    
    
 

      <section id="whatwedo">
              <div class="container-fluid">
                <h1><span style="color: rgb(133,52,146);">&#43;</span>What we do</h1>
                    <div class="cols">
                          <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h2>ADVERTISING</h2>
                                    <img src="images/advertising.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-3">  
                                    <h2>GRAPHIC DESIGN</h2>
                                    <img src="images/graphic_design.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">  
                                    <h2>BRAND IDENTITY</h2>
                                    <img src="images/brand_identity.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">      
                                    <h2>BRAND GUIDELINES</h2>
                                    <img src="images/beard.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>    
                               
                          </div>
                          <div class="row no-gutters">
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h2>PRINT MANAGEMENT</h2>
                                    <img src="images/print.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-3">  
                                    <h2>CREATIVE DIRECTION</h2>
                                    <img src="images/creative_direction.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h2>EDITORIAL DESIGN</h2>
                                    <img src="images/ed_design.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>    
                                <div class="col-md-3">
                                    <h2>AND LOTS OF OTHER STUFF</h2>
                                    <img src="images/other_stuff.jpg" class="image" style="width: 100%; height: 300px;">
                                    <div class="overlay">
                                        <div class="text"> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</br> Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Alias cum repellat velit quae suscipit.</div>
                                    </div>  
                                </div>    
                                 
                            </div>
                    </div>
             </div>         
    
        </section>
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: share your HTML for the page too.

Comment: @Paul Just updated.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is the height!
Try with min-height.

Answer (score 1):

It is really hard to find errors in your code when this amount of it is provided. You should post relevant html, use css-flexbox or bootstrap grid (or any other grid system). You can find Bootrstrap v.4 grid only (withot any other styling) [here](https://github.com/m-spyratos/bootstrap-4-grid). Hope it helps!